# fglrx problem with amd gpu drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, radeon, fglrx

i have a radeon r7 APU and 20.04 ubuntu and im trying to install the drivers. i downloaded 4 fglrx files (fglrx-core, fglrx, fglrx-dev, fglrx-amdcccle) and when i try to install the fglrx-core i get the error:

> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-57-generic (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.302/build/make.log for more information.
> dpkg: error processing package fglrx-core (--install):
> installed fglrx-core package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10

and heres the make.log

```
DKMS make.log for fglrx-core-15.302 for kernel 5.15.0-57-generic (x86_64)
Thu 12 Jan 2023 07:29:24 PM +0330
/usr/sbin/dkms: line 80: cd: /var/lib/dkms/fglrx/15.302/build: No such file or directory
make.sh: 42: [: !=: argument expected
AMD kernel module generator version 2.1
doing Makefile based build for kernel 2.6.x and higher
rm -rf *.c *.h *.o *.ko *.a .??* *.symvers
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-57-generic/build SUBDIRS=/var/lib/dkms/fglrx-core/15.302/build/2.6.x modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-57-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:217: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-57-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:88: kmod_build] Error 2
build failed with return value 2
```

and the other files are all dependante on this one.

i tried purging them and installing them again but that didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

`fglrx` drivers are obsolete and can't be installed to modern Ubuntu releases for many years.

Comment: so how to i install the proper drivers for my gpu? its the only thing thats on the amd website.

Comment: You don't need to install any drivers. AMD drivers are included in Ubuntu.